# how to build a url on django outside a template

Tags: python, django

I have an application that when the user instance is created a signal is dispatched to send an email. I am implementing a signal to send an SMS.

On my email HTML template I have this line that redirect the user, I need to send the same link on the SMS.

`<a href="{{ uri }}{% url 'password-reset-and-active-account' uidb64=uid token=token %}">Aqui</a>`

the parameters used there is passed through this context

```
context = {
    'user': user,
    'uid': urlsafe_base64_encode(force_bytes(user.pk)).decode("utf-8"),
    'token': default_token_generator.make_token(user),
    'uri': settings.ABSOLUTE_URI
}
```

how can I **build this URL outside Django Templates**, because the `{% url 'password-reset-and-active-account' %}` will not work outside the template right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you can use the reverse method. This is equals the url template tag but for python programming.

```py
from django.urls import reverse

# ...
url = reverse('password-reset-and-active-account')
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/urlresolvers/#reverse

Comment: You guys can help me with this?

Comment: django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'password-reset-and-active-account' with keyword arguments '{'uidb64': ('MTA2OTE',), 'token': ('5tg-cf18ce5dc73b4536887c',)}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['account/password-reset-and-active-account/(?P<uidb64>[0-9A-Za-z]+)-(?P<token>.+)/$']

Comment: this is what i ran `reverse('password-reset-and-active-account', kwargs={'uidb64': uid, 'token': token})`

Comment: keyword arguments '{'uidb64': ('MTA2OTE',), 'token': ('5tg-cf18ce5dc73b4536887c',)}' not found, the ('MTA2OTE',) and ('5tg-cf18ce5dc73b4536887c',) means that your are sending  a tuple in the argument... Try it using only the string without the tuple

Comment: I tried to do uid[0] and token[0] but both returned the first letter of the string

Comment: "1 pattern(s) tried"... Se if the token and the uidb64 is in the correct format too...